# Java - Cast a Map

Tags: java, casting, dictionary

How can I cast a `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<String,String>` in the cleanest way?

Is there a way to do that without iterating over the map?

Thanks

Comment: Why is a `Map<String, String>` declared as `Map<Object, Object>` in first place?

Comment: It's just an abstract example, it could be Map<Integer, String> to be casted to Map<Long, String>

Comment: If the latter is your concrete requirement, then you really have to loop over it. But if it was *actually* a `Map<String, String>` which is incorrectly been declared as `Map<Object, Object>`, then you could just have casted on `(Map)` (without generic type arguments).

Comment: You seem to be confused between casting, which is just telling the compiler something that is already true, and conversion, which is operating on the data.

Comment: There are some cases where a map of objects is appropriate, but it is the exception not the rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to explain why the simple solution doesn't work and why you never, ever should use this.

Assume you could cast `List<Object>` to `List<String>` (the same applies to Map, just a simpler interface). What would you expect to happen from the following code:

```
List<Object> m = Something;
m.add("Looks good.");
m.add(42);
List<String> s = (List<String>)m; // uhuh, no we don't want that.
String myString = s.get(1); // huh exception here.
```

Now you CAN hack it indeed using Bohemians/Chris solution, but you basically destroy Java's type system. **DON'T DO THAT.** You don't want a `List<String>` to contain an Integer! Have fun debugging that later on - the additional code of looping through all variables will avoid lots of headaches and hardly is a performance problem.

If there's a reason to declare the Map as taking an Object instead of a String someone may add any object to it - usually you should be able to avoid this with a better generic.

Comment: More real life example. See `java.util.Properties extends Hashtabl<Object,Object>` but you want to use and `Map<String,String>` instead of using `getProperty` method of Properties. So you have to convert first.

Comment: And I really like your answering style ... reminds me on how I approach many questions ;-)

Comment: I hate when tool decides whether I should do something or not. What if I need to cast `List<String>` to `List<Object>`, I can't redesign my code, it's two 3rd party libraries, so I should map one list to another one just to do it in java'sh way?

Comment: @deathangel No you should do it that way to avoid breaking the type system.

Comment: What do I do i map case? `stringList.stream().map(e -> (Object) e).collect(toList())`? What exception will I get If I just cast `List<String>` to `List<Object>`? Every rule has an exception.

Comment: @death The given example can be trivially adapted to produce the same runtime exception if you cast `List<String>` to `List<Object>` (hint: what can you add to a `List<Object>`? What do you expect a `List<String>` to contain?)

Comment: Alternatively, this is a good reason to only use immutable data structures!

Comment: Never? Often you don't control the API returning the map (or List). I'm using GAE memcache which returns Map<String, Object>) from getAll(). I put the objects in there so I KNOW they are <String, String>. Sometimes you need to cast to avoid an unnecessary copy of a large map. Isn't that the point of casting? Why does the compiler complain in this case?

Answer (score 14):

The actual answer is:

```
Map<Object,Object> valueMap = ...;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String,String> targetMap = (Map)valueMap;
```

Comment: Because that doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh wow, it doesn't. Thanks BalusC. Well, I edited my snippet to have a bit of a dirty hack :-)

Comment: Some explanation of why (Map)valueMap works but (Map<String,String>) doesn't?

Answer (score 9):

If you want something clean, you must convert "deeply"! keys and values.

Using Java 8 stream, this take only a few lines:

```
static public Map<String, String> toStringString(Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> map) {
        return map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                    e -> e.getValue().toString()
                ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  Map<String, String> castOnlyStringValues(final Map<String, Object> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(x -> String.class.isAssignableFrom(x.getValue().getClass()))
              .map(x -> (Entry<?, ?>) x).map(x -> (Entry<String, String>) x)
              .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on [Chris J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788177/java-cast-a-map/7788191#7788191), here's his "hack" code in action, showing it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Object, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    valueMap.put("foo", "bar");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> targetMap = (Map<String, String>) ((Object) valueMap); // hack alert!
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : targetMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(key + "=" + value); // prints foo=bar :)
    }
}
```

Wow! No runtime exceptions :)

Comment: Horrible, horrible hack. Anyone using that in production code should be taken out and shot in my opinion ;) Note that I assume you only mentioned that, because it's a neat trick and not as an advice to use it. Always fun though to show people how a `Map<String>` can contain an integer..

Comment: Well... I did say it was a dirty hack ;-)

Comment: While I agree that this is usually this is wrong, there're cases where a map of objects is appropriate.