# Cast a Map to a map with super class generic types

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a `Map<K, V>` and want to cast it to a `Map<K, U>` where `V` extends `U`. Example: I want to go from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>`. This problem exists with all kinds of collections.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7788177/6094756) already has an answer with a "hacky" solution and one that explains why casting generic types is generally a bad idea. But let's revisit the example from the answer from Voo:

```
List<String> m = Something;
m.add("Looks good.");
m.add("42");
List<Object> s = (List<Object>)m; // (1) does not compile
List<Object> t = (List)m; // (2) compiles with warnings
Object myObject = s.get(1);
```

A few questions about this example:

- Why does this (1) not compile? Is a way to make it compile other than the hack (2)?
- What could possibly go wrong when casting a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>` since all Strings are objects?

**My concrete problem:**

I have got a `Map<Integer, Map<Vector2i, MyClass> > map = ...` that contains a map for each level. The map on level 0 is of type `Map<Vector2i, MySubClass> special = ...`. I want now `special` to be part of `map` for the key 0 so that accesses to the `map` for key 0 can be treated as a normal `Map<Vector2i, MyClass>` object.

The situation is read-only, meaning that writing to `map` and `special` happens separatedly.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288084/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listobject

Comment: I'm curious *why* you think you need that cast. This could be an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What could possibly go wrong when casting a List<String> to a List<Object> since all Strings are objects?

Look at it from this perspective: If it's a `List<Object>`, everything can be added to it. So, this can go wrong, for example:

```
List<Object> t = (List)m; // (2) compiles with warnings
t.add(1235); // it's a List<Object>, so we can add an Integer

for (String s : m) { // m only contains Strings, right?!
    System.out.println(s.length());
}
```

And you'll hit a `ClassCastException` once `s` is not a `String` as expected.

**[Addendum]**

> Why does this (1) not compile? Is a way to make it compile other than the hack (2)?

I'm not sure, what your actual problem is, so I'm just guessing. But the first time I was faced with a similar issue, was something like this:

```
/* Just example; functionality does not matter, just that it accepts List<Number> */
public static void printNumbers(List<Number> numbers) {
    numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Above's utility method takes a `List<Number>` and just prints each of them. Now you typically have `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, etc. in your code. But the following code would node compile:

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
printNumbers(integers);
```

Now, instead of doing wild casting (and in case you have control over the imaginary utility method of course), do the following:

```
public static void printNumbers(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Now the method accepts `List`s of any kind of `Number`s. But you cannot add anything to the list (beside `null`) inside the method, because the actual type is not known at runtime.

This explanation is probably a little casual. If you want to get more in detail, search for the "PECS rule" ("producer extends, consumer super"). Same would apply for any generic types, such as `Map`s well, of course.

Comment: I see. I was focused on the 'reading' part and totally forgot that when writing it is still possible to mess things up.

Comment: One other thing to add is the notion of 'type erasure', whereby generics are a compilation time notion. The cast can be done at run time by doing `List<Object> s = (List<Object>) List.class.cast(m);`, but then it is a Pandora's box. For some extra insight, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524751/cast-object-to-generic-type-for-returning

Comment: The ´? extends´ solution resolves my problem, thank you.